# Will dependency injection dispose the following registration?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

By looking into the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for dependency injection it is clear that DI will dispose of the object that is injected by DI according to their lifetime.
I'm little confused/not sure what will happen in the following case with `BlobContainerClient` object. Will it get disposed of with `EventProcessorClient`.

```
services.TryAddScoped<EventProcessorClient>(p =>
{
    var storageClient = new BlobContainerClient("connectionString", "containerName");
    var connectionParam = p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EventHubSettings>>();
    return new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, connectionParam.Value.SomeValue,
        connectionParam.Value.SomeValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the same docs

> The container calls Dispose for the IDisposable types it creates. Services resolved from the container should never be disposed by the developer. If a type or factory is registered as a singleton, the container disposes the singleton automatically.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#disposal-of-services)

Looking at the code example neither the [EventProcessorClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient?view=azure-dotnet) class or the [BlobContainerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) class implement the `IDisposable` interface. This means the dependencies will not be "explicitly" disposed (through an `IDisposable.Dispose()` method call).

What will happen is the objects `storageClient`, `connectionParam` and the `EventProcessorClient` will be marked for clean up by the Garbage Collector.

Now given this is a [`Scoped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#service-lifetimes) service lifetime these events will happen when the scope is disposed. Either through (with a web application) when the request ends, or the scope is explicitly disposed (with a `using` statement).

To add (from the example) if the `BlobContainerClient` implemented the `IDisposable` interface it would not be automatically disposed when the scope ends. This is because the object was constructed manually (not via the lifetime scope object) so therefore would not be tracked by the scope.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that if `BlobContainerClient` was disposable, then the DI framework wouldn't dispose it since it is created manually. It would be safer to inject that as well.